# Sql join only on the first match

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, greatest-n-per-group

I don't know how to perform the the following case.

I have the sales info in a table:

```
Number of Bill (key),
Internal number (key),
Client,
Date (month-year),
Product group,
Product,
Quantities,
Total,
Sales man.
```

I need to joint this sales tables with the annual forecast sales table that is the next one:

```
Date (key),
Group product(key),
Sales man (key),
Total.
```

In each tables the combination of the key is the primary key. I need to add in the sales tables the forecast. For this I need to add the sales of the forecast in the real sale only on the first match of date, group product and sales man, so the total of forecast sales don't get bigger than it is (a sales man can sell the same group product, to the same client, in the same day on multiple times).

Answer (score 1):

> .. only on the first match of date, group product and sales man ..

You can use window functions for this, consider using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ... )`. First match has row number of `1`.

More information and examples (sales!) [can be found from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).